# How to use the tf.global_variables_initializer() function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build my TensorFlow code.  However, the following error message occurs:

> Attempting to use uninitialized value unit_1_2/sub2/conv2/DW

Unintialized DW is defined as follows:

```
  kernel = tf.get_variable(
      'DW', [filter_size, filter_size, in_filters, out_filters],
      tf.float32, ***initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(
          stddev=np.sqrt(2.0/n))***)
```

However, my code doesn't include the `tf.global_variables_initializer()` 
because I think that I already defined the initializer in the kernel source (`tf.get_variable`).

Is this the error?  Do I have to write the `tf.global_variables_initializer` code after `tf.get_variable` code?

Comment: Right before you call ``sess.run(your_own_ops)``, you should initialize the variables using ``sess.run(init_op)`` where ``init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())``. This way, TF will actually assign initial values to all variables in the graph. The ``tf.random_normal_initializer`` only tells you're gonnal use normal distribution, it does not assign the values right away.

Comment: Richard_wth, Thanks you very much.